# Local CoroutineScope().launch { }, how long does the created coroutinescope live in memory?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am having trouble understanding how memory management works on Android with locally created coroutines. Here is some code:

```
 init {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        val result = workerA.runSuspended(paramA)
        liveDataA.postValue(result)
    }
}
```

For a short suspend function call, I want to launch a coroutine once, then I no longer need the scope. I understand you cannot cancel the scope when written like this. But my main questions are:

1. what happens once the job is done? Is the coroutineScope garbage collected?
2. Is the scope guaranteed to stay alive until the job finishes?
3. What happens if the runSuspended stays stuck? Will there be a memory leak if the parent object is garbage collected?

Comment: I haven't found a source, but from my experimentation, I think the underlying coroutine system holds references to all launched Jobs until they complete or are cancelled. This Job will hold a reference to its parent Job, which ultimately is the Job element of a CoroutineContext belonging to the CoroutineScope that launched the coroutine.  So if I'm correct that means 1. the CoroutineScope is eligible for collection once it's reference is dropped, but this has no effect on coroutines that it launched.

Comment: 2. The scope remains alive in the sense that its CoroutineContext's root Job is still alive, even though the scope itself no longer exists (it was just a brainless pass-through to a CoroutineContext). 3. A coroutine that suspends forever without being cancelled is leaking everything it references. This pattern is very similar to Threads. When you call `start()` on a thread, it lives until completion, regardless if you're still holding a reference to the Thread object.